# Bash exercise-glob style...?

Tags: bash

I have an exercise, in which I have to print all the files in the current directory, which start with the letter `[a-z]`, or ending with any number of these: `[1/3/5/7/9]`

As I think it has to be in globstyle... and the code is:

```
ls a[-z]* || *[13579]
```

but for some reason that doesn't work.
 maybe I should use Extended Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to your ls command are not regular expressions at all but shell globs. And shell globs are interpreted by the shell *before* the command is executed. You can do:

```
ls [a-z]* *[13579]
```

Note that this may contain duplicated (file `a1` will be listed twice) so you can do:

```
ls [a-z]* *[13579] | sort | uniq
```

Comment: +1; but note that this will misbehave if any filenames contain the newline character, since `sort` and `uniq` will split by lines. To address that, you can bypass the issue by using a more restrictive glob; something like `echo [a-z] [a-z]*[!13579] *[13579]`. Also, if you keep the pipeline approach, `sort | uniq` can be shortened to just `sort -u`.

Comment: (And some sort of handling is probably needed for the case that no file matches one of these patterns. Nullglob, perhaps?)

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about newlines in file names :) As to no matching file I'd just redirect stderr to /dev/null, since if no file matches, the glob will stay as is on the command line.

Comment: So guys, how do I actually ask the or logical operator in glob-style, like, if it starts with [a-z]||[13579], how do I ask that "or" , and how do I ask the && operator, like it starts with a-z and ends with 1/3/5/7/9 ---> will it just be [a-z]*[13579] ? Thanks!

Comment: @user1923376 - globs don't have "operators" like that.  But you can often get similar functionality from a range.  For example, `[a-z14]*` matches any file that starts with a letter, a `1`, or a `4`.  And as ruakh suggested, you can negate a range with a `!`.  So you use two globs - `[a-z]*[!13579]` and `*[13579]` - to match (1) all files that start with a letter and not an odd number and (2) end in an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
printf '%s\n' [0-9]* *[a-z]
```

Only using `globs`

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob