# Bash ls (glob-style)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls

I have an excersise in which I have to print all the file names which are contained in the current folder, which contain in the them one of the letters `[a-k]` and `[m-p]` and `[1-9]` atleast 1 time (each).
I probably have to use `ls` *(glob-style)*.

Comment: I'd use `grep` and a regex: `ls -1 | grep -E "your_regex"`

Comment: well, I don't know what regex is, and I actually have to use ls I think.. thx

Comment: huh? I have to use ls [glob-style]

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/14004201/722238

Comment: this question was originally mine.. xD and no- that doesn't help. Now I'm actually solving this thing with egrep, but not sure how do I write that the string must contain atleast 1 time [a-k] [m-p] [1-9] in reg expressions..

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3):

If order is important then you can use globbing:

```
$ ls *[a-k]*[m-p]*[1-9]*
ajunk404  am1  cn5
```

Else just `grep` for each group separately:

```
ls | grep "[a-k]" | grep "[m-p]" | grep "[1-9]"
1ma
ajunk404
am1
cn5
m1a
```

Note: `ls` will show directories if you really only want files use `find` inside:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep "[a-k]" | grep "[m-p]" | grep "[1-9]"
```

Answer (score 2):

A 100% pure bash (and funny!) possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
a=( *[a-k]* )
b=(); for i in "${a[@]}"; do [[ "$i" = *[p-z]* ]] && b+=( "$i" ); done
c=(); for i in "${b[@]}"; do [[ "$i" = *[1-9]* ]] && c+=( "$i" ); done
printf "%s\n" "${c[@]}"
```

No external processes whatsoever! No pipes! Only pure bash! 100% safe regarding files with funny symbols in their name (e.g., newlines) (and that's not the case with other methods using `ls`). And if you want to actually see the funny symbols in the file names and have them properly quoted, so as to reuse the output, use

```
printf "%q\n" "${c[@]}"
```

in place of the last `printf` statement.

**Note.** The patterns `[a-k]`, `[p-z]` are locale-dependent. You might want to set `LC_ALL=C` to be sure that `[a-k]` really means `[abcdefghijk]` and not something else, e.g., `[aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJk]`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If order isn't important, and the letters appear once or more, you can use chained greps.

```
ls | egrep "[a-k]" | egrep "[m-p]" | egrep "[1-9]"
```

If order matters, then just use a glob pattern

```
ls *[a-k]*[m-p]*[1-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

To be complete, you need to search all the combinations:

```
ls *[a-k]*[m-p]*[1-9]* *[a-k]*[1-9]*[m-p]* \
   *[m-p]*[a-k]*[1-9]* *[m-p]*[1-9]*[a-k]* \
   *[1-9]*[m-p]*[a-k]* *[1-9]*[a-k]*[m-p]*
```